# Deny direct access to PDF files in php web folder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, pdf

There is a fully running PHP site that can only be accessed when logged in with ID/password.

I have been asked to add a function to the site that uploads PDF files and show existing PDF files in the browser.

So I achieved this by using iframe to embed PDF files in the browser.

But the problem is, the PDF files shouldn't be directly accessible (shouldn't be opened when accessing www.aaa.com/pdf/test.pdf), and must only be shown in the site so that only authorized users can view the file.

So I tried a few things :

1. .htaccess : I'm not too familiar with PHP/HTML so searched some answers on stackoverflow and tried them without success.

such as

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
Require local
```

and so on. It obviously blocked direct access, but also didn't allow the PDF to be shown from the site (www.aaa.com/showPDF.php). Come to think of it, the above methods seem to only allow the files to be read when opened from the physical server.

2. Moving the PDF folder outside of webroot : I succeeded moving the upload folder outside of webroot and also uploading to it, but then iframe doesn't work since PHP can't find the PDF file. A workaround was to use headers and PHP readfile(), but I can't seem to modify the headers from where I'm from since the headers are already sent beforehand in files that I cannot modify.

I think I'm making this overly complicated, and I think an appropriate .htaccess file will simply do, but don't have much knowledge in this area. Would really appreciate help here, thanks!

Comment: Your second solution is the way to go. I don't understand what problems you have with http headers? A file on the server does not have any http headers.

Comment: you are probably making things more complicated starting from the iFrame. Also you should use sessions to identify and verify if a user has the right to open a specific page

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Solved and posted my answer, when I tried to send another header on showPDF.php, I got some warnings saying that I coudn't modify the headers since they were already sent. Turns out I could upload the files outside webroot, but couldn't read them. So I had success modifying my first solution. Thanks!

Comment: @LelioFaieta I do use sessions to authorize the user for specific pages, but since a PDF file isn't a web page, I din't know how to do it. Thanks, solved it using .htaccess.

Comment: _“A workaround was to use headers and PHP readfile(), but I can't seem to modify the headers from where I'm from since the headers are already sent beforehand in files that I cannot modify”_ - what files are you talking about? This should be implemented rather as a “stand-alone” script to begin with, not load the full code of whatever CMS/framework you are using there to begin with. (Maybe load _some_ of it to get the basic session functionality and user access check working - but anything that already creates output has no place being involved in this to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe I had to include some system_init.php which includes session control, headers and other initializing functions.
But I made a fresh file that doesn't require system_init.php and added session controls. Your other comment in my answer was a big help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Seems it was simple enough.
>
> ```
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from all
> Allow from www.aaa.com
> ```
>
> worked. Thank you for your suggestions!

=======================================

Edit : above didn't work.

In fact, I didn't have permission to access outside my webroot.
So I stored the pdf files inside a folder within my webroot and denied access from all by using :

```
Deny from all
```

in .htaccess.

After that, since iframe was denied by .htaccess, I tried to print the contents of the PDF by using file_get_contents(). But this required setting header information such as

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filePath));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
echo $contents;
```

But the php page that shows the contents of the PDF file (showPDF.php) already sent out headers during initializing, and I didn't have rights to modify that part.

So I made a fresh php file (pdfviewer.php), added session information, and added the above 4 lines. After that I iframed pdfviewer.php within showPDF.php and it finally worked.

I think this problem was REALLY specific to my current situation but hope someone finds it useful.

Also, thanks @CBroe since I realized I was wrong and got some hints!

Comment: Are you talking about this in regard to a script solution directly on your server, that reads the PDF file contents and passes it on to the client? Because if you are still just referring to the original PDF URL in your iframe, this will _not_ achieve what you think it does.

Comment: @CBroe Oops, maybe it was the cache or something, but now it doesn't work. Could have swore it worked when I was writing the answer.  I don't exactly understand your question, but I only want the files to be seen inside www.aaa.com/showPDF.php (which is password/session protected).

Comment: `Allow from` is about the requesting clients, and those are most likely not identical to the server that `www.aaa.com` runs on, so using this makes no sense here in the first place. _“but I only want the files to be seen inside www.aaa.com/showPDF.php”_ - you can not achieve that by directly referring to the PDF’s URL, you need some sort of PHP/scripting solution.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, this time I REALLY got it to work. editing
Your "cannot achieve this by directly refering to the PDF's URL was a BIG hint.
First, I modified .htaccess to "Deny from all".
Second, I made another page pdfviewer.php that requires a login session and a filename argument.
Finally, I showed pdfviewer.php inside showPDF.php.
Thank you so much!